# How can i retrieve data in a related model which needs a reference to the calling model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a controller and two models, a user and a store.
A user has_many stores. Inside stores I have a method get_items which lists items.
get_items itself needs a reference to the user.
What I have done now is the following

```
@items = user.stores.first.get_items(user)
```

this looks weird to me since the initial caller has to pass itself as an argument to the get_items method.
What would you recommend?

best,
phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've defined the relation in two directions,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

then you have access to the `user` that a store belongs to within the `Store` instance. So you should be able to write

```
def get_items
   do_something_with user
end
```

and it should use the correct user. The call to get_items could then be

```
@items = user.stores.first.get_items
```

I would personally rename `get_items` to `items`.

Comment: hi, yeah, I am missing the bi directional relation in the model, thats the point thank. you are right the "get" is not needed.. thank you very much